# App worked on VSCode but didn't after deployed to Lambda, no error in CloudWatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this piece of code that runs perfectly fine locally.

But after I deployed it to AWS Lambda, it didn't execute as expected, plus, it did not print any errors to CloudWatch for me to see what had happened.

I assume that it was because of the `async/await` that caused it but it seems to be correct.

Did anyone witness it before?

```
module.exports.fetch = async event => {
  const getParametersResponse = await ssm.getParameters({
    Names: [
      "TOKEN",
      "ACCESS_KEY"
    ]
  })

  await axios
    .get(url)
    .then(async (res) => {
      return downloadFile(res.data, project)
    })
    .then(async () => {
      const readStream = await zipFile.openReadStream(entry)
      return sendToDrive(readStream, project, gdriveKey)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error")
    })
};
```

CloudWatch details:

[image]

Comment: `async/await` do not block the main thread. Once that the main thread completes, the lambda execution also completes, no matter if there are other threads running in the background, the lambda execution is controlled by the thread running the lambda handler.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. So, what was the error that caused the function not being executed?

Comment: @DanielG. But it you return a promise (which is the case here, because the function is `async`), Lambda will wait for it to resolve...

Comment: "it did not print any errors to CloudWatch for me to see what had happened" << It did, though: "Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"

Comment: A recommendation, though: Don't mix `await` and `then`. You already have `await`, so no need for all the `.then`s and the `.catch`. (The `.catch` is currently problematic anyway and will just _hide_ the error behind a generic message `"error"` so you'll never know what's going on.) It can just be `const res = await axios.get(url); await downloadFile(res.data, project); const readStream = await zipFile.openReadStream(entry); return await sendToDrive(readStream, project, gdriveKey);`. (And if you do want to catch an error, you can add `try`/`catch`, but there is no need - Lambda logs it anyway!)

Comment: It was a bad habit from me. I'll modify it. And thank you for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your function has a timeout set to a too-small value. By default, the timeout is set to 3 seconds, and if I'm not mistaken that's what can be seen in the logs you've pasted. Increase the timeout and the function should be able to execute.

Comment: Thank you so soo much!! It's been bordering me for days to find the error. Everything works like charm now.